# How do I return process.uptime(); from milliseconds into a human readable format?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I'm making a discord bot. I've tried this -

```
bot.on('message', message => {
if (message.content === '!uptime') {
    var time = process.uptime();

    function dhm(ms) {
        days = Math.floor(ms / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        daysms = ms % (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        hours = Math.floor((daysms) / (60 * 60 * 1000));
        hoursms = ms % (60 * 60 * 1000);
        minutes = Math.floor((hoursms) / (60 * 1000));
        minutesms = ms % (60 * 1000);
        sec = Math.floor((minutesms) / (1000));
        return days + ":" + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + sec;
    }
    message.channel.sendMessage(dhm(time));
   }
});
```

In chat, this returns - `0:0:0:0`

```
// Uptime
bot.on('message', message => {
 if (message.content === '!uptime') {
    var time = process.uptime();
function dhm(t){
var cd = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    ch = 60 * 60 * 1000,
    d = Math.floor(t / cd),
    h = Math.floor( (t - d * cd) / ch),
    m = Math.round( (t - d * cd - h * ch) / 60000),
    pad = function(n){ return n < 10 ? '0' + n : n; };
  if( m === 60 ){
h++;
m = 0;
  }
  if( h === 24 ){
d++;
h = 0;
  }
  return [d, pad(h), pad(m)].join(':');
}
  message.channel.sendMessage(dhm(time)); 
 }});
```

This returns `0:00:00`

I'm trying to convert the value of `process.uptime();` into days, hours, minutes, and seconds. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: FWIW the documentation says it returns uptime in seconds, not milliseconds.

Comment: console log process.uptime() to see what you get

Answer (score 0):

Btw, the first comment given is not 100% correct. According to the latest documentation the return value includes fractions of a second. Math.floor() should be used to obtain whole seconds. Thus, to obtain the uptime in milliseconds the `process.uptime()` value needs to be multiplied by `1000`. The following code example may do what you want. As the example uses a different format you may want to adapt the code to the format you prefer which should be straightformward.

You can trial a variation of this code on [repl.it](https://repl.it/@mwittig/Format-processuptime-with-milliseconds)

```
var uptime = process.uptime();
console.log("Uptime raw:", uptime)
const date = new Date(uptime*1000);
const days = date.getUTCDate() - 1,
      hours = date.getUTCHours(),
      minutes = date.getUTCMinutes(),
      seconds = date.getUTCSeconds(),
      milliseconds = date.getUTCMilliseconds();


let segments = [];

if (days > 0) segments.push(days + ' day' + ((days == 1) ? '' : 's'));
if (hours > 0) segments.push(hours + ' hour' + ((hours == 1) ? '' : 's'));
if (minutes > 0) segments.push(minutes + ' minute' + ((minutes == 1) ? '' : 's'));
if (seconds > 0) segments.push(seconds + ' second' + ((seconds == 1) ? '' : 's'));
if (milliseconds > 0) segments.push(milliseconds + ' millisecond' + ((seconds == 1) ? '' : 's'));
const dateString = segments.join(', ');

console.log("Uptime: " + dateString);
```